# With pyppeteer how to make a request with client cert?

Tags: python-3.x, puppeteer, pyppeteer

I have the need to reach a page using client certificate with pyppeteer, 
i have seen that its possible with puppeteer itself [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1319#issuecomment-371503788), 
but my attempts lead to an invalid state errror with python3. Im not sure whether my attempt is entirely correct, but it follows the spirit of the issue comment in puppeteer. I would expect it to be possible, hence my attempts, here is the error:

```
[E:pyppeteer.connection] connection unexpectedly closed
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<Connection._async_send() done, defined at /home/data/experim/jaenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py:69> exception=InvalidStateError('invalid state',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/data/experim/jaenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 73, in _async_send
    await self.connection.send(msg)
  File "/home/data/experim/jaenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 467, in send
    yield from self.write_frame(True, OP_TEXT, data.encode('utf-8'))
  File "/home/data/experim/jaenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 919, in write_frame
    yield from self.ensure_open()
  File "/home/data/experim/jaenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 646, in ensure_open
    ) from self.transfer_data_exc
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/data/experim/jaenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 79, in _async_send
    await self.dispose()
  File "/home/data/experim/jaenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 170, in dispose
    await self._on_close()
  File "/home/data/experim/jaenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 153, in _on_close
    f'Protocol error {cb.method}: Target closed.',  # type: ignore
asyncio.base_futures.InvalidStateError: invalid state
```

This is the attempt that leads to the above error:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
from pyppeteer.network_manager  import Request
import requests

async def interceptor(interceptReq, cert,key):
    res = requests.get(interceptReq.url , cert=('../../widshared/certexp.cer','../../widshared/certpriv.pem'))
    if not res.ok:
        return await interceptReq.abort('connectionrefused')
    else:
        return await interceptReq.respond({
             'status': res.status_code,
             'headers': res.headers,
             'body': res.content
             })

async def main():
    browser = await launch(headless = True )
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setRequestInterception(True)
    with open("../../widshared/certexp.cer", 'r') as cr:
        cert = cr.read()
    with open("../../widshared/certpriv.pem", 'r') as cr:
        key = cr.read()
    page.on('request', lambda interceptReq: asyncio.ensure_future(interceptor(interceptReq, cert, key )) )
    await page.goto('https://client.badssl.com')
    await page.screenshot({'path': 'clientbadssl.png'})
    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```